# Call POST API from .net core with Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Tags: .net, post, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have to call a post api from my .net core web application which accepts parameter as form-data. I can call the API from post man but I get an error when calling from .net core application. Look at my code below and parameters from post man.

```
// POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
            try 
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                        "Bearer", 
                        "**************************************");
                var multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                multiContent.Add(new StringContent("Test Name"), "Name");
                multiContent.Add(new StringContent("Test Type"), "Type");
                multiContent.Add(new StringContent("100"), "Min");
                multiContent.Add(new StringContent("100"), "Max");
                multiContent.Add(new StringContent("100"), "Amount");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await 
                client.PostAsync
                ("https://test/api"
                , multiContent);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }  
            catch(HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");   
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What exception\error do you get?

Comment: I get an custom error which is sent by the api in case there is an issue with parameters.